# Start SSH in CentOS rescue mode

Tags: centos, rescue

I am booted into rescue mode after inserting the DVD. OS is CentOS 6.7 64

I've tried

```
cd /mnt/sysimage
chroot /mnt/sysimage
service sshd restart
```

which gave back `service command not found`.

What do I do next?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Could you just run `/usr/sbin/sshd` without the service trappings?

Comment: Also, do you have networking setup?

Comment: Yes network is setup and pinging. There is no /usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: That also isn't in the chroot under `/mnt/sysimage`?

Comment: Correct (chara limit)

Comment: Is that perhaps part of why you're in rescue mode?  Has something bad happened to the disk so it lost `/usr/sbin` and other stuff?

Comment: I'm not too sure, it's been hacked for sure but I don't know what they have done. Booting gives "PCI: Fatal: No config space access function found".

Rescue mode should be able to start SSH though? or FTP, anything to get access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27285/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-teddy291).

Comment: Why would you want to start SSHD in rescue mode of a machine that you know is hacked? I would copy the important files onto an USB drive, but definitely not make  a compromised machine able to communicate over any network, internally or externally.

Comment: http://blogs.reliablepenguin.com/2009/07/07/remote-access-via-ssh-with-redhat-rescue You missed `mount /dev/pts` I am sure if you have correct ISO and linux on local disk FS it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do same thing with CentOS 7.2 to save some files. I booted into rescue mode after inserting the DVD and open the shell.

First I configure network with `nmtui` than I started ssh service without getting `#bash`:

```
#sh-4.2:service sshd start
```

and it started. But couldn't reach my files from shell and I get `bash`

```
#sh-4.2:chroot /mnt/sysimage
#bash:cd 'myfiles'
#bash:scp /* user@IPADDRESS:/path
```

This worked just fine. I tried to start ssh service and it didn't work. Do it with shell.

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7/RHEL 7 if rescue mode mounts your CentOS/RHEL/Fedora under /mnt/sysimage succesfully, then `systemctl start sshd.service` will not work in chroot (it detect chroot). You have to run SSHD manually with full path:

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

If rescue mode does not detect your system properly, you have to mount all needed stuff to chroot environment by hand:

```
mount <your_root_device> /mnt/sysimage
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/sysimage/pts
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/sysimage/proc
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sysimage/sys
```

Then chroot and run SSHD like above. Rescue mode does not have own SSHD, you have to use the one from chroot. Don't forget to configure network interface (by `nm-tui`, `ifconfig` or `ip`) and default route (`route` or `ip`). This could be done in chroot too by `ifup <interface>` or `/etc/init.d/network start` and maybe by `systemctl start NetworkManager`.